# Can you change the value of a char in an if statement?

Tags: c, string

Here's an example:

```
char x[20] = "aa";
int y = 2;
if(y==2) {
   x[20] = "bb";
}
printf("%s",x);
```

If we run this code aa gets printed instead of bb, is there a way to change the value of x from the if statement?

Comment: With char x[20] = "aa" you are saying "Allocate place for 20 chars in memory and assign 'aa' to it, and if you print x[0] then 'a' will be printed after assignment. 
With x[20] = "bb" you are trying to assign to index 20 of the 'a' array value "bb" (which is btw string not char) and I am not sure how this can be compiled at all.

You could do following 
if (y == 2) {
x[0] = 'a';
x[1] = 'a';
}

Or you could use strcpy ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the string `bb` into the string `x`, by using [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

```
strcpy(x, "bb");
```

---

`x` would be a character if it was something like this `char x = 'a';`. Notice the single quotes (used for a character), instead of double quotes (used for a string). In the character case, the assignment operator, would indeed work.